# R -- Undefined truth values in if statements

Tags: r

What is the *"standard protocol"* for running a condition that has an undefined truth value through an `if` statement?  Namely, I'm referring to `length`. I am working on a function, `grep.dataframe` that will extract (with `grep`) or replace (with `gsub`) values in a data frame without having to write loops every time. Here's where I'm at:

```
> dat <- data.frame(x = letters[1:3])
> grep.dataframe('f', dat)
# character(0)
```

So I decided to add an `if` statement so that `grep.dataframe` returns something a bit more widely comprehensible if there are no matches, like `NULL`. `if(length(d) == 0) NULL else d` seems nice. But that doesn't look nearly as pretty as `if(is.integer(x))`.  Consider the fact that there are 159 `as.` or `is.` functions in the `base` package alone. I couldn't find one that was for this issue. So then, my question is, **How do those published R developers handle this situation in their code?**

I thought of doing this, which doesn't seem half bad I guess.

```
has.length <- function(x)
{
    if(length(x) > 0) TRUE else FALSE
}

> has.length(character(0))
# [1] FALSE
> has.length(1)
# [1] TRUE
```

which led to

```
> df1 <- data.frame(x = 1)
> if(!has.length(df1)) NULL else df1
#   x
# 1 1
> df2 <- data.frame(x = numeric())
> if(!has.length(df2)) NULL else df2
# [1] x
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

which **does not** work (thanks @MrFlick for correcting that). 
I would like to know the elegant, R developer way to do this.

Cheers.

**ADD :** So that people have an idea of what I'm doing, here are three results. The function is working nicely now, as agstudy's answer did the trick. Now all I have to get right are the inherits of classes.

```
> args(grep.dataframe)
function (pattern, X, sub = NULL, ...) 
NULL

> dat <- data.frame(x = letters[1:4], y = c('b', 'd', 'a', 'f'))
> grep.dataframe('a|f', dat)  ## returns a named list of values found by column
# $x
#   value row
# 1     a   1

# $y
#   value row
# 1     a   3
# 2     f   4

> grep.dataframe('a|f', dat, sub = 'XXX')  ## returns the gsub'ed data frame
#     x   y
# 1 XXX   b
# 2   b   d
# 3   c XXX
# 4   d XXX

> grep.dataframe('h', dat)
# NULL
```

Comment: The problem with that code is `d<-data.frame(a=numeric()); has.length(d)` would return true. And i'm guessing since it has no rows you would like to return false.

Comment: Right.  See, I knew it wasn't going to be that easy. Haha. That was what I meant actually.  Made an edit.

Comment: So your `has.length` is telling you if an object has a non-zero length, but you really want to know if it's "empty". The problem is that every data type or class may have a different definition of what it means to be empty. Clearly `data.frame` has a different idea than a `factor`. You could think of defining a generic `is.empty` function. Then each class can have it's own way of telling you if it's empty.

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  I added some results to my post.

Comment: @MrFlick, would you happen to know how to make one of the `...` arguments unavailable so it cannot be passed to my function?  Reason is I'm already using `value = TRUE` in `grep`, but I'm also passing `...` to `grep`.

Comment: You might want to open a new question so i can see the code and make a more informed answer. But if you don't want a particular value to be passed through the `...`, you can either define it as a parameter on your main function call so it never goes into the `...` or you can change `...` to list, make sure the element is removed. and then do a `do.call` with that list rather than `...`.

Comment: I think I got it.  I just `grepl`ed out `value = TRUE` from the dots list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
 check_x <- function(x) if(length(x)) x else NULL
 x <- character(0)
 check_x(x)
 x <- 'a'
 check_x(x)
 [1] "a"
```

or also simply to omit the return :

```
check_x <- function(x) if(length(x)) x
```

Comment: I think `if(length(x))` was what I was trying to get at.  Since `0`, it evaluates to `FALSE` in an `if` statement, correct?

Comment: @RichardScriven yes exactly.