# Pass data frame to function, preserving the original column attributes

Tags: r, attributes, structure

I should know this, but I don't.  And that's because factors in R can be an absolute nightmare.  This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856089/r-pass-some-but-not-all-further-arguments-with). I'm hoping a few of you might be able to explain in a bit more detail than the R manuals about how to preserve the column attributes when passing a data frame to a custom function.  So far, the most useful information I've dug up was from Hadley's *Advanced R Programming* site.  But that section is quite short.  Here's what I have:

---

**Edits:** I've added the [source code](https://github.com/rmscriven/myUtils/blob/master/R/gsub-dataframe.R) to my GitHub  (EDIT: link goes to `gsub.dataframe.R` now). Also, I think I may have a good way to determine whether to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the new data frame.  Or, as a much easier alternative, I could add a `stringsAsFactors` argument.  Is it possible to use `...` for more than one set of further arguments? Like having `...` be the further arguments to `grep` *and*`data.frame`?

---

Set up some data

```
set.seed(24)
num <- rep(1, 10); int <- 1:10; fac <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, TRUE)
D <- data.frame(num, int, fac); D$char <- as.character(letters[1:10])
```

Here's a call to the custom function, and the result.

```
(newD <- grep.dataframe("6|(a|f)", D, sub = "XXX", ignore.case = TRUE))
#    num int fac char
# 1    1   1 XXX  XXX
# 2    1   2   B    b
# 3    1   3   C    c
# 4    1   4 XXX    d
# 5    1   5 XXX    e
# 6    1 XXX   C  XXX
# 7    1   7 XXX    g
# 8    1   8   B    h
# 9    1   9   B    i
# 10   1  10 XXX    j
```

I haven't done anything, but have tried everything I can think of, to preserve as much information about the columns as I can (i.e. `class(x) <-`, `attr(x, "name") <-`, `attributes(x) <-`, `I(x)`, etc.).  The result you see above is absolutely correct as it reads.  However, the result below is troubling.  I could use a little help with getting the final data structure to match the original data structure.  I'm thinking a `switch` statement might do the trick?

Note that

```
> args(grep.dataframe)
function (pattern, X, sub = NULL, ...) 
NULL
```

with the `sub` argument calling `gsub` when not `NULL`

As always, I appreciate the help.

---

**Note :** I took the advice of Hadley (why wouldn't you?) and split this into two functions.  My answer below is a new function that only calls `gsub` for regular expression matching.

Comment: Do you expect the class of column `int` to remain integer despite inserting `XXX`? (Maybe you expect that `XXX` to be coerced to `NA`?)

Comment: Good question.  I haven't thought that through fully, but I'd probably want that one coerced to `character` in case the data frame had a column of mixed alphanumerics (i.e. 24EX6, or something similar). Perhaps `NA` would be better?

Comment: Another main thing is...what the heck happened to the `character` column?

Comment: The behaviour is expected since `gsub` returns character vectors, and `data.frame` by default coerces strings to factors.

Comment: Take a look at [this related solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9215233/489704). You could replace your `dc <- data.frame(ap)` with `dc <- colClasses(data.frame(ap), sapply(X, class))`, using `colClasses` as defined at that link.

Comment: After a bit of thought, I think it would be best if a column of `typeof` "integer" or "double" only be changed if the entire column is changed by `gsub`.  More `if` statements!!

Comment: What is the goal of your `grep.dataframe` function? Currently it seems to be doing many things and it is not clear what the purpose is. Why does ... need to go to both `grep` and `data.frame()`? Why would you want to do a regular expression replacement on a numeric column? (Also, never use `mode()`, it only exists for S+ compatibility)

Comment: @hadley, it's kind of an experiment actually, and so I can improve my skills.  With `sub = NULL`, the function returns a named list of matches, by column, showing both the value of the match and the row number in which it was found.  I added `sub` later for the option to sub the pattern.  When `sub` is a pattern, the original data frame is returned with the pattern sub included.  [The bottom of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850861/r-undefined-truth-values-in-if-statements) shows a few results.

Comment: @hadley, I also noticed last night that it is possible to change the `class` and `storage.mode` of integers and doubles under certain conditions.  Should I be messing with that?

Comment: @RichardScriven Sounds like you need two different functions. And no, you shouldn't need to mess with class, and definitely not `storage.mode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column class problem was solved with this little dandy of a function that re-assigns the classes based on the originals.

```
.reClass <- function(x, type)
{
    switch(type,
           character = as.character(x),
           integer = as.integer(x),
           factor = as.factor(x),
           numeric = as.numeric(x))
}

> args(gsub.dataframe)
function (pattern, replacement, data, use.nums = FALSE, ...) 
NULL
```

`use.nums` is for "use numerics?", whether to replace a pattern on numeric columns. `D` is the original data being fed to have it's columns pattern-replaced (under certain conditions).

```
> sapply(D, class)
#        num         int         fac        char 
#  "numeric"   "integer"    "factor" "character" 
> x <- gsub.dataframe("2|A", "XXX", data = D, ignore.case = TRUE)
> x
#    num int fac char
# 1    1   1   C  XXX
# 2    1   2   B    b
# 3    1   3 XXX    c
# 4    1   4 XXX    d
# 5    1   5   C    e
# 6    1   6 XXX    f
# 7    1   7   C    g
# 8    1   8 XXX    h
# 9    1   9   B    i
# 10   1  10 XXX    j
> sapply(x, class)
#       num         int         fac        char 
# "numeric"   "integer"    "factor" "character"
```